# How to grant access to resource group without subscription permission to deploy services?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Im this scenario I'm hosting several resources for several projects in one azure tenant.
Additionally I have multiple azure subscriptions with corresponding resource groups per project:

- Azure Subscription A -> Resource Group A -> VMs, DNS, Bastion Host... for project A
- Azure Subscription B -> Resource Group B -> VMs, DNS, Bastion Host... for project B
- Azure Subscription C -> Resource Group C -> VMs, DNS, Bastion Host... for project C

In the Azure AD I would like to create groups like `Project A`, `Project B`, `Project C` and grant them  role permissions to the dedicated resource groups.

But unfortunately if I grant the role `Contributor` this also includes the permission of the subscription to add new services. I just want to enable them to manager their resources (access the vm through bastion host) without givin them permission to add new services.

Comment: Are you giving contributor role to subscription or resource group level?

Comment: I didn't changed the subscription after optainig it from the partner portal. I added the contributor role to the resource group.

Comment: You may check out the below link for creating custom roles

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-custom-role-powershell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can restrict the user not to create the resources in the resource group in two ways,

1. You can grant contributor permissions to each individual resource,
   that way user won't be able to create new resources, only modify
   existing ones (he would be able to delete resource).
2. Combination of RBAC and [AzurePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview).The users that have
   assigned contributor access have access to all resources in their
   resource groups. In [Azure Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#general)  you can use a policy like
   Allowed resource types, Not allowed resource types, Allowed location
   will enable you to specify the resource types that your organization
   can deploy.

There is a similar scenario that you can [find here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29092).

Comment: Is it possible to set reader, contributor to the subscription itself? - Would the reader role permit new deployments?

Comment: Contributor -manage everything except granting access to resources and Reader -Lets you view everything, but not make any changes. So, Contributor, its self contains reader role

Comment: Sorry my explanation was misleading. Does the reader role on a subscription include the permission to add new services?

Comment: By [Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader), you cannot add or create new service